# Are there any modern Linux distributions that still support /dev/audio?

Tags: linux, audio, linux-distributions

I'm in the process of trying to debug a program that uses the legacy OSS `/dev/audio` interface to play sounds. However, Ubuntu and others no longer include a `/dev/audio` interface. Are there any relatively-modern Linux distributions that I could download in a virtual machine to test with?

Comment: Doesn't [oss-compat](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=oss-compat&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) solve this?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it's supposed to, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your computer uses PulseAudio (Ubuntu does), run the program via **`padsp`**:

```
padsp yourprogram
```

It will intercept attempts to open `/dev/audio`, `/dev/dsp`, and other related devices (using  a LD_PRELOAD shared library) and send the sound directly to PulseAudio.

For systems that use plain ALSA, the equivalent is **`aoss`** from the "alsa-oss" package.

```
aoss yourprogram
```

`aoss` should work on Ubuntu too, since by default ALSA itself is rerouted through PulseAudio, but better use `padsp` in that case.

---

Most kernels also have the **`snd-pcm-oss`** module, which provides real `/dev/dsp` and `/dev/audio` devices using ALSA:

```
sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss
yourprogram
```

I've heard it doesn't work as good as `aoss`, though, and I'm not sure whether it works *at all* when PulseAudio is running.

Answer (score 0):

Support from /dev/audio was removed in Linux kernel version 4.15, so you want to look for a disto such as CentOS 7.x or anything based on an older kernel.  Make sure you install the snd-pcm-oss and snd-mixer-oss kernel modules using modprobe.